# How to correctly translate a pose along an axis?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, posestamped, tf2, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a pose of my robot `base_link` in the `map` frame. I'd like to translate this `0.2 m` along the robot `x-axis` so the
point is in front of the robot. To do this I've tried the following but all it seems to do is give the `transformed_pose`
the same position in the `x-axis` of my transforms `x-axis` translation. How might I fix this?

```
transform = TransformStamped()
transform.transform.translation.x = 0.2
transformed_pose = tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_pose(pose, transform)
```

transformed_pose:

```
header:
    seq: 0
    stamp:
    secs: 0
    nsecs:         0
    frame_id: ''
pose:
    position:
       x: 0.4
       y: 0.0
       z: 0.0
    orientation:
       x: 0.0
       y: 0.0
       z: 0.5
       w: 0.0
```

I've tried to troubleshoot this issue in [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/374078/how-to-translate-a-pose-in-rospy/), which may be a useful reference.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376849/how-to-correctly-translate-a-pose-along-an-axis?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2021-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohamed ahmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/37345/mohamed-ahmed/) on 2021-05-07**:
This answer might be helpful
https://answers.ros.org/question/222306/transform-a-pose-to-another-frame-with-tf2-in-python/

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2021-05-07**:
I use this method to get the pose of my robot `base_link` in the `map` frame actually and it works great. How would I adapt this method to get the pose of the robot `base_link` + 0.2 m in the `x-axis` in the `map` frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some playing around, the following code achieved me to translate my pose along the `x-axis`.

```
transform = self.tf_buffer.lookup_transform(frame, required_position, rospy.Time(0), rospy.Duration(1))
initial_pose = PoseStamped()
initial_pose.pose.position.x = 0.2
translated_pose = tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_pose(initial_pose, transform)
```

---

Originally posted by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) with karma: 501 on 2021-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1